# Why is my second level drop down menu not aligned with the first menu?

Tags: html, css

As shown on the demo below, the submenu1 leaves white padding on its left below the submenu and is not dropping down on the same level as submenu. What am I doing wrong in the CSS?

[image]

```css
.nav ul, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 10pt;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 40px;
    list-style: none;
}
.nav ul {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.nav ul li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    border-right: gray thin solid;
    border-bottom: gray thin solid;
    background-image: url(Images/Icons/top-nav-back.jpg);
    display: inline-block;
}
.nav ul li ul {
    display: none;
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
    z-index: 1002;
}
.nav ul li:hover {
    background-image: url(Images/Icons/nav-back.jpg);
}
.nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
.nav ul li:hover ul li {
    clear: left;
}
.nav ul li ul li ul li {
    display: none;
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
    z-index: 1002;
}
.nav ul li ul li:hover ul li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
.nav a {
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
}
.nav a:hover {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav" style="height:40px;">
    <ul>
        <li style="width: 65px; height: 40px;"><a href="~/" runat="server">menu</a></li>
        <li style="width: 85px; height: 40px"><a href="~/" runat="server">menu</a>
            <ul>
                <li style="width: 160px; height: 40px"><a href="~/" runat="server">submenu</a></li>
                <li style="width: 160px; height: 40px"><a href="~/" runat="server">submenu</a></li>
                <li style="width: 160px; height: 40px"><a href="~/" runat="server">submenu</a></li>
                <li style="width: 160px; height: 40px"><a href="~/" runat="server">submenu</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li style="width: 125px; height: 40px"><a href="#" runat="server">menu</a>
            <ul>
                <li style="width: 220px; height: 40px"><a href="~/" runat="server">submenu</a></li>
                <li style="width: 220px; height: 40px"><a href="~/" runat="server">submenu</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li style="width: 220px; height: 40px"><a href="~/" runat="server">submenu1</a></li>
                        <li style="width: 220px; height: 40px"><a href="~/" runat="server">submenu1</a></li>
                        <li style="width: 220px; height: 40px"><a href="~/" runat="server">submenu1</a></li>
                        <li style="width: 220px; height: 40px"><a href="~/" runat="server">submenu1</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li style="width: 95px; height: 40px"><a href="~/" runat="server">menu</a></li>
        <li style="width: 65px; height: 40px"><a href="~/" runat="server">menu</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @TylerH it has been fixed. Thanks for paying attention; I have a list of all repaired images the script has repaired, I'll doublecheck those soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without rewriting your CSS properties, change this selector:

```css
.nav ul li ul li:hover ul li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left:100%;
    top:0;          
 }
```

To this:

```css
.nav ul li ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin-top: -40px;
}
.nav ul li ul li:hover ul li {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `top:0` to your style for the nested ul elements and make your li elements `position:relative`. That will move the ul to the top of the li that contains it.

You can also reduce your css code by using the direct-child selector. If you make your ul elements get the following:

```
.nav ul li>ul {display:block}
```

It will only show the ul directly after the li you hover on, not the further menus.

Answer (score 0):

See **[this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5rQht/)** (third menu item).

You can do it by amending the code like this:

```css
.nav ul li ul
{
    ...
    height:0px;
    ...
}

.nav ul li ul li:hover ul li
{
    ...
    top:-40px;
    ...
}
```